# AngularJS pagination with laravel model - pagination bar is not displayed properly

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, laravel-5

Here is my AngularJS code for building the pagination with [angular bootstrap pagination](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/):

```
$scope.employees = [],
$scope.currentPage = 0,
$scope.numPerPage = 2,
$scope.totalItems = '',
$scope.maxSize = 2;

$scope.getEmployee = function (offset) {
    $http.get('/employee/'+offset).then(function (response) {
        $scope.employees = response.data.data;
        $scope.totalItems=  response.data.totalRows;
        console.log($scope.totalItems);
    });
};

$scope.getEmployee(0);

$scope.getPage = function () {
    $scope.getEmployee($scope.currentPage === 1 ? 0 : $scope.currentPage);
};
```

Trying to list 2 employees per page (Now i have 6 rows in mysql query)

**Laravel controller**

```
public function getTotalEmployees($offset)
{
    $result =  Company::limit(2)->offset($offset)->get();
    return response()->json(array('data'=>$result,'totalRows'=>Company::count()));
}
```

query will give correct output but the paginationbar is not properly displayed.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="emp in employees">{{emp.name}}</li>
</ul>
<pagination
    ng-model="currentPage"
    total-items="20"
    max-size="maxSize"
    boundary-links="true"
    ng-change="getPage()">
</pagination>
```

I think its the problem with `totalItems` value but i can't fixed it here is screenshot of the pagination bar

[image]

I can't select the next and previous buttons its disabled

Comment: You select 2 items from your database (`Company::limit(2)`) and parse it in a pagination list based on 2 items per page. SO why do you expect that there are more pages then one? Its normal that next is disabled when there is no "next" page, isnt it?

Comment: So i need to get all the rows ?? but it is crashed when table has morethan 20000 rows??

Comment: 20000 items is not a problem when you just output one attribute like "title" as a text. It does depend on how much data you output and on the complexity of your "row" HTML structure.

Comment: there is so much data so think its bad idea

Comment: So, than loading just the data you need to display on the current page should be fine. But you need an other API endpoint to get the "total count" of your items to create a nice pagination.

Comment: Currrent APII always returns the total row count so how can i modify the above code to achive the expected result

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144318/discussion-between-jabaa-and-lin).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somethink like this. I'm not that familiar with laravel but it should work with mini modifications for you. I added an other controller action in laravel which return you the total count of your items. This API endpoint is called on `this.$onInit` which is a methods available since AngularJS 1.5. It will be called when the controller is initialized. Here is a simple **[fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ynxpoyyy/2/)** with an pagination example.

#### AngularJS controller

```
$scope.employees = [],
$scope.currentPage = 0,
$scope.numPerPage = 2,
$scope.totalItems = 0,
$scope.maxSize = 2;

this.$onInit = function () {
    $scope.getEmployee();
    $http.get('/employee/getTotalCount').then(function (response) {
        $scope.totalItems = response.data.count;
    });
};

$scope.getEmployee = function () {
    $http.get('/employee/getItems/'+ ($scope.currentPage * $scope.numPerPage) +'/' + $scope.numPerPage).then(function (response) {
        $scope.employees = response.data.data;
    });
};


$scope.getPage = function () {
    $scope.getEmployee();
};
```

#### Laravel controller

```
public function getTotalCount()
{
    $companies = Company::all();
    return response()->json('count' => $companies->count());
}

public function getItems($offset, $limit)
{
    $result = Company::limit($limit)->offset($offset)->get();
    return response()->json(array('data'=>$result));
}
```